# Excel 365 Look for key words in one cell to populate another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one cell which contains a long string. I'd like to look for key words in that string (key words being on a list) and then based on that enter a value in another cell something like this: -

Cell A1 ="Marvel Comics Men's Tee: Guardians of the Galaxy Groot (XX-Large)"

Keyword list
"Guardians of the Galaxy" or "GOTG" or "Guardians Galaxy" = "Guardians of the Galaxy"

"Groot" = "Groot"

Output to cell B1=" "Guardians of the Galaxy, Groot"

If that makes sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with the inputs and outputs.

[image]

Use TEXTJOIN as an array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$4,A1)),$E$1:$E$4,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott; I'll give that a go tomorrow :-)

Comment: Okay, so that didn't work. the output was just lots of 0,0,0,0,0, getting longer with each row.  
The formula I used was this:  
 =TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!A1:A33,rockoff_12.10.18.with_individua!F2)),Sheet1!B1:B33,""))  
The column with the string that is searched for keywords is:<br/>rockoff_12.10.18.with_individua!F  
The table of keywords is:  
Sheet1!A1:A33  
And the corresponding strings to enter as output are:  
Sheet1!B1:B33  
The column where I want the keyword to be entered is:  
rockoff_12.10.18.with_individua!AL

Comment: I give up trying to add formatting to my comment! I hope you can decipher it!!!

Comment: 1.  Are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter? 2. you need to make all the references absolute except `rockoff_12.10.18.with_individua!F2`  And you will only get `0` if there is nothing in the corresponding return.  outside of that it is too hard for me to trouble shoot.  As you can see it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help again Scott. I'm saving using the Ctrl+Shift+Enter combo (it adds square brackets to the formula?) I've also tried matching your formatting but I'm not sure what you mean by 'absolute references', is that the $s? If the cell to be searched is F2, the cell with the output is AL2, the 'input/output' table is on a separate sheet to keep it tidy and that sheet is called Sheet1 with input column A1 to A33 and output column B1 to B33 would this formula be right?  `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$33,F2)),Sheet1!$B$1:$B$33," "))`

Comment: So, I've just tried the formula on a new spreadsheet with only the columns that are required for the formula (just like in your example) and it worked fine. So what's going wrong in my sheet?

Comment: Update on the last comment. The formula works fine for a single row but when I copy it to the entire column (20,000 rows) it doesn't update the value of the cell in the formula that it initially looks at (A1) and when I manually change the second row's formula to A2 it also changes all the other rows to the same value.

What's going on?

Comment: You need to enter the formula in the first cell. Confirm with ctrl-shift-enter. Then copy down the length of the data. Do not array enter the formula all at once into all the cells.

Comment: Can I make this formula search for 'Guardians of the Galaxy' rather than anything containing 'Guardians' 'of' 'the' or 'Galaxy' because I'm getting multiple returns due to individual words popping up on other rows that are being matched?